# Vertical Align On Drop Down Menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align my text in a drop down menu. I have been following the suggestion in Stackoverflow and used display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle but it does not appear to work. It just sticks each text at the top of each drop down cell.

My drop down menu is #results.

The code and CSS is as below.

```
 <div class="container">
  <div id="jumbo" class="jumbotron">
   <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Search" id="keyword">
   <input type="button" id="myBtn" value="Go">
   <div id="results">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="trainstation" style="background-color:blue;width:100%;margin:auto;height:100px;">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
   #results {
   width:94%;
   position:absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   background-color:white;
   border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
   display:none;
   text-align:left;
   z-index:10000;
   }
   #results .item {
   padding:3px;
   height:50px;
   font-family: arial;
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   border-bottom:1px solid #c0c0c0;
   }
```

EDIT

Sorry the code above is actually centering everything on ONE line..ie ONE drop down with all the suggestions in that one drop down

Comment: It is advisable that you prepare a jsFiddle demonstrating your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: block` and use `line-height` for horizontal center

**CSS**

```
#results {
   width:94%;
   position:absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   background-color:white;
   border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
   text-align:left;
   z-index:10000;
   }
   #results .item {
   padding:3px;
   height:50px;
   font-family: arial;
   display:block;
   vertical-align:bottom;
   border-bottom:1px solid #c0c0c0;
   line-height: 50px;
   }
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/dbymfkh2/1/)**

Comment: I replaced vertical-align:bottom with vertical-align:middle to make the text go into the middle

Comment: @user2635961 , vertical-align does't work with display:block !

Answer (score 0):

Set the `line-height:` of your item class to be equal to the height of the div, so something like

```
 #results .item {
 padding:3px;
 height:50px;
 font-family: arial;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
 line-height:50px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #c0c0c0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. To make it work I needed to change the display:table-cell to display:block